# Different ways of declaring a function in C++

Tags: c++

I have come across the following code snippet in C++ and I have no idea what it means;

```
#include <iostream>

char (&some_function(int (&some_input)));  

int main ()
{
  // main code here 
  return 0;
}
```

How is `some_function` a function? what kind of syntax is this? where is the body? 
I'm sure this is only a C++ syntax as it doesn't compile in C.

Edit:
Actual code with above style:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>  
char (&ArraySizeHelper(T (&array)[N]))[N];  
#define arraysize(array) (sizeof(ArraySizeHelper(array)))
```

Comment: Does `char& some_function(int& some_input);` look fine to you?

Comment: yes, a function that returns a reference to a char and takes a reference to an int. Whats' with the extra brackets? where is it's body?

Comment: If so, then why are the extra brackets confusing? `Whats' with the extra brackets?` ask the person that has written the code. Now you have updated your post with a  __very__ different code.

Comment: I have added the actual code, how does this function have no body?

Comment: It doesn't compile in C because C doesn't have references. C++ does. It's just a function declaration, not a definition. You said as much in the title.

Comment: Uhh.  the code in the edit is completely different to the original code in the question. Are you saying you did not actually come across the original code ?

Comment: yes, the first coded is my way of understanding the style. How are the very different?

Comment: The `[N]` parts are significant

Comment: lol @ the original author starting with the template and then reverting to `#define` unnecessarily

Comment: (Some people (like (extra parentheses))).